# Bezier Curves ( Path ) - More less constant speed when traversing through T

Tags: performance, math, position, bezier

Strict facts:

- Unfortunately i am not a math-guru
- I generate a bezier path by drawing it with my finger on the screen
- I have an object that follows this path
- I traverse this path when engine calls **Tick**(float **fDelta**) on the object in this manner:

> if( **m_fBezierTime** < 1.0 ) 
>   {
>
> **m_fBezierTime** += 0.1f * **fDelta**;
>
> **m_vPosition** = m_Bezier.CalculatePosition(**m_fBezierTime**);
>
> }

- This kind of approach gives 'huge' acceleration between points that have a higher distance than those being close to each other.
- I have heard this is normal behavior of the Bezier

Now the question :

- How can i make this speed at least 'close' or '~'  to constant ?

Thanks for any comments on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and fast solution: Get a bunch of regularly distributed points on your Bezier curve (for example 10 points per curve) like you are doing now and measure the Euclidian distance between those points (meaning: sqrt((x_1 - x_2)² + (y_1 - y_2)² … )). This should be a good measure for the length of the full curve, which you can use than to traverse with nearly constant speed.

There is more nifty stuff going on around here: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html
but that might be overkill.